# Windows login URL not working for separate site collection

Tags: 2013, custom-login-page

I have a web application with multiple site collection. I have enabled form based authentication with custom login page. For windows authentication user I have a button on this page which opens up default authentication login pop up. below is URL which I used:

```
http://abcuniversity/_windows/default.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2f_layouts%2f15%2fAuthenticate.aspx%3fSource%3d%252F%255Fwindows%252Fdefault%252Easpx&Source=%2F_windows%2Fdefault.aspx
```

But this URL is working for only root site collection. It is not working with `/sites/college1` path site collection. It throws HTTP 404 error.

```
http://abcuniversity/sites/college1/_windows/default.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2f_layouts%2f15%2fAuthenticate.aspx%3fSource%3d%252F%255Fwindows%252Fdefault%252Easpx&Source=%2F_windows%2Fdefault.aspx
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Can you add the complete URL that is failing

Comment: I have updated my question with both URLs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working with below URL:

```
http://abcuniversity/_login/default.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fsites%2fcollege1%2f_layouts%2f15%2fAuthenticate.aspx%3fSource%3d%252Fsites%252Fcollege1&Source=%2Fsites%2Fcollege1
```

It still uses root site URL as login but uses separate site collection URL to redirect once User is authenticated.

Comment: Good to hear that but What was the problem . is it redirect now correctly and dynamically  for all subsite without error ?

Comment: I need to change Return URL manually for each site collection manually. I am looking for dynamic solution if there is any.

Answer (score 0):

Try to configure the managed path of this web application by following the mentioned steps below :

- in Central Administration > Application Management > manage Web Application > Select your application > from the above ribbon > select Managed path > Make Sure the WildCard Inclusion for `sites` have been added if not try to add it.

[image]

Comment: I am also here if you need any clarification ,

Comment: sites is default managed path created by SharePoint. And as far as I know it is wildcard inclusion.